# What does this hospital mean with the following OAuth requirements?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

We've got a hospital as a customer which wants to have an app developed. This app will probably make use of various ways of validation, of which OAuth2 is one. They have a list of requirements, of which one kind of puzzles me:

> For every user session, the app needs to generate an unpredictable
>   "state parameter". The app needs to validate the "state value" for
>   every request which is sent to the redirect URL; the "state" needs to
>   be recorded with all authorization requests; and the "state value" has
>   to be validated with the access token which it receives.

Although they don't specifically mention it I guess this talks about OAuth. I've got some experience with OAuth2. I know what access tokens and refresh tokens are. But this story is above my head. What kind of `"state parameter"` and `"state value"` are they talking about?

Could anybody shed some light on this story?

Answer (score 2):

This is about the `state` parameter that OAuth 2.0 has defined in the authorization request as a RECOMMENDED parameter (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) used to protected against cross-site request forgery and to correlate requests and responses in general:

> state
>
> ```
>      RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
>      state between the request and callback.  The authorization
>      server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
>      to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
>      cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe they chose to write an OAuth 2.0 client application requirement on their own words. The specification states that:

> The client MUST implement CSRF protection for its redirection URI. This is typically accomplished by requiring any request sent to the redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request to the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g., a hash of the session cookie used to authenticate the user-agent). **The client SHOULD utilize the "state" request parameter to deliver this value to the authorization server when making an authorization request.**

(emphasis mine, read the whole story in [section 10.12 of the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12))

For a more step-by-step guided approach on how to use the state parameter you can refer to [Using the State Parameter](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth-state). This page mentions Auth0, but the process should be the same for any other OAuth 2.0 compliant server. Also note that the specific steps assume a browser-based application and as such store the unpredictable state parameter in Web storage. Other types of clients would use other stores, but the principle remains the same.